# Spring Cloud Contract: cannot specify regex for field that can/cannot be null

Tags: groovy, null, dsl, spring-cloud-contract

Currently trying to create contract for my DTO.
There are some fields that can have some value(literally - date) or can be null.
So I've tried some variations:
    1 - `endDate: $(anyIso8601WithOffset()) | $(!nonBlank())`
    2 - `endDate: $(anyIso8601WithOffset() | regex('null'))`
    3 - `endDate: $(anyIso8601WithOffset() | optional(null))`

but all these cases doesn't work.

In most cases getting such exception:

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':mdf-service:generateClientStubs.
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.internal.ServerDslProperty.or() is applicable for argument types: (org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.internal.OptionalProperty) values: [(null)?]
>     Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), grep(), grep(java.lang.Object), any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)`

So that don't know for now what can be used for such case.